# Trying to add a WMS layer to Openlayers 3 but not showing anything

Tags: javascript, wms, cartography, openlayers, maps

I have started with OpenLayers 3 recently and I need to add a layer from an own WMS. I have been trying this:

```
map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    layers: layer,
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [4, 40],
        zoom:2
    })
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    preload: Infinity,
    url: 'http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/',
    params:{
        'LAYERS':"RE007RUS_municipis", 'TILED':true
    }
})
});
```

But this is showing nothing, I don't know what to do. With OpenLayers 2 I had the map working, but I need it with OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to your map extent compared with the WMS layer extent.

When I unzoom with my code, I get the same issue as the one in the comment from Jonatas e.g  `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/?SERVICE=WMS‌​&VERSION=1.3.0&R…256‌​&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STY‌​LES=&BBOX=4569030%2C‌​-10997100%2C4569120%‌​2C-10997010"`

Try below code and it works (tested)

```
  var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      preload: Infinity,
      url: 'http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/',
      params:{
        'LAYERS':"RE007RUS_municipis",
        'VERSION': '1.1.1',
        'TILED': true
      }
    })
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    layers: [layer],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: [4.093781, 39.957649],
      zoom: 11
    })
  });
```

It should return an image similar to below.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert. The layer must be declared before the map.

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        preload: Infinity,
        url: 'http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/',
        params:{
            'LAYERS':"RE007RUS_municipis", 'TILED':true
        }
    })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    layers: layer,
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [4, 40],
        zoom:2
    })
});
```

Comment: That could be something, but is not the problem here. I changed the code by deleting the line `layers: layer,` and adding a `map.addLayer(layer)` at the end. The problem must be something else...

Comment: I tried your code and this is what it returns: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://ide.cime.es/menorca/wms/base_referencia/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&R…256&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&BBOX=4569030%2C-10997100%2C4569120%2C-10997010"`.

Comment: Maybe it's missing some configuration on server side.

Comment: An XML response from a WMS GetMap request is certainly a case of an error message being returned from the WMS, and almost certainly the error is with the request made.  In your code snippet you have  `CRS=EPSG%3A4326` so we are expecting a BBOX in decimal degrees, but have instead `BBOX=4569030%2C‌​...` which look to me like they could be in metres, so that would be an error.